# how to check if a dropdownlist contains the value saved from database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, drop-down-menu

I have 3 dropdowns: Property, capital, corporate. each has a different values.
I am saving the selection that users make when filling the form inside a hidden field (hfFromEntity). I have problem retrieving the information for reloading the form. I want to compare the value of the hidden field with all 3 dropdowns and select the one that has the value in it. But don't know how to do it.
Here how I populate the dropdowns.

```
     private void PopulateDropDownValues()
     {
         DataTable dt = objMrsManager.GetAllProperties();
         DataTable dc = objMrsManager.GetlAllCapitals();
         DataTable ds = objMrsManager.GetlAllCorporates();

        if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                drpFromProperty.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr["NAME"].ToString(), dr["ENTITYID"].ToString()));
                drpToProperty.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr["NAME"].ToString(), dr["ENTITYID"].ToString()));
            }
        }

        if (dc != null && dc.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in dc.Rows)
            {
                drpFromCapital.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr["NAME"].ToString(), dr["ENTITYID"].ToString()));
                drpToCapital.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr["NAME"].ToString(), dr["ENTITYID"].ToString()));
            }
        }

        if (ds != null && ds.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Rows)
            {
                drpFromCorporate.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr["NAME"].ToString(), dr["ENTITYID"].ToString()));
                drpToCorporate.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr["NAME"].ToString(), dr["ENTITYID"].ToString()));
            }
        }

        drpFromCorporate.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Corporate--", "0"));
        drpToCorporate.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Corporate--", "0"));
        drpFromCapital.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Capital--", "0"));
    } 


    private void LoadWireTransfers()
    {
        if (WireTransfers != null && WireTransfers.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataRow dr = WireTransfers.Rows[CurrentPosition];

            hfWireTransferID.Value = dr["WTID"].ToString();   
            hfWFromEntity.Value = dr["WFromEntity"].ToString();
            hfWToEntity.Value = dr["WToEntity"].ToString();

            //I want to compare the hfWFromEntityValue with each dropdownlists
            if (hfhfWFromEntity.Value == drpFromProperty.????)
            {
                drpFromProperty.Items.Clear();
                drpFromProperty.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr["WFromEntity"].ToString()));
            }

            //This doesn't work. I don't know how else I can do
            if (drpFromCapital.Items.Contains(new ListItem(hfWFromEntity.Value)))
            {
                drpFromCapital.Items.Clear();
                drpFromCapital.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr["WFromEntity"].ToString()));
            }

            if (hfhfWFromEntity.Value == drpFromCorporate.????)
            {
                drpFromCorporate.Items.Clear();
                drpFromCorporate.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr["WFromEntity"].ToString()));
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can search for the text that shown in the dropdown list by using:

```
    if (drpFromCapital.Items.FindByText(hfWFromEntity.Value) != null)
    {
        drpFromCapital.Items.Clear();
        drpFromCapital.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr["WFromEntity"].ToString()));
    }
```

To get search by value you need to use:

```
if (drpFromCapital.Items.FindByValue(hfWFromEntity.Value) != null)
{
    drpFromCapital.Items.Clear();
    drpFromCapital.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr["WFromEntity"].ToString()));
}
```

Comment: @mbadevloper This method doesn't get the value. It returns null for all three dropdowns.

Comment: you can use this method **drpFromCapital.Items.FindByText** to find by dropdownlist text that it show for the user, for search by value you need to use **drpFromCapital.Items.FindByValue** instead:
if (drpFromCapital.Items.FindByValue(hfWFromEntity.Value) != null)
{
        drpFromCapital.Items.Clear();
        drpFromCapital.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr["WFromEntity"].ToString()));
}

Comment: I already tried FindByValue. Still I get null. It won't match with the hiddenfield's value.

Comment: debug it and make sure that the hidden field have a value.
May be you have extra space in the end of the string so use hfWFromEntity.Value.Trim() and make sure if that is match capital and small letters.
I test it and its work for me.
Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

This finds the item in the combobox that represents your string, and gives you the item you can select:

```
var item = drpFromProperty.Items.FindByValue(hfhfWFromEntity.Value)
if (item != null)
    item.Selected = true;
```

Comment: This method is for combobox not dropdown list

Comment: It doesn't work. I get null for my item. hfWFromEngity.Value = a value but it doesn't find it inside the dropdown list .